# Creating Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a Android App project in which user have two option, Sign In and Sign Up. 
I have got few question:

1- In Sign Up Activity, how can I store the data of the user? 
2- In Sign Activity, How can I check that the entries enter by the user are correct and the user already have a account by us. 
3- In Sign Up Activity, the Data entered by the user should come to me, So that I will able to contact the user of my app.

I searched over the internet, and the outcome is that I have to use SQLite Database. 
Kindly guide me about this process.
Thanks in Advance.
p.s like Facebook, we have to sign up for creating new account and sign in, I want to create this type of app.

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1- In Sign Up Activity, how can I store the data of the user?`

You need to maintain a database for this. Read this tutorial [data - storage tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

`2- In Sign Activity, How can I check that the entries enter by the user are correct and the user already have a account by us`
Now, you need to check with your server and do the authentication part. You need to incoporate webservices and use android network modules. [network operations](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html)

`3- In Sign Up Activity, the Data entered by the user should come to me, So that I will able to contact the user of my app`

Just keep track of the textview where the user types the uname and pwrd. check the [textview apis](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)